# Case insensitive search in Path Range Query for Marklogic

Tags: java, indexing, marklogic, marklogic-9

How can we do case insensitive search for path range queries? 
I want to make case insensitive search for path:

```
/pathSyntax = (case insensitive value of $Type)
```

Sample Query Format for Path range search , I need to make this path range query search as case insensitive :, do I need to make changes in Indexes also created for it?

```
let $xyz:= cts:and-query((
 cts:collection-query(concat("xyz://", val, "/test")),
 cts:path-range-query("/pathSyntax", "=",$Type)
))
```

Below is range path index :

```
{
  "scalar-type": "string",
  "path-expression": "/pathSyntax",
  "collation": "http://marklogic.com/collation/",
  "range-value-positions": false,
  "invalid-values": "reject"
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could index your path with a collation that is case-insensitive.

For instance,
[`http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1`](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/encodings_collations#id_40354) is a case/diacritic insensitive English character encoding, or `http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S2` which is diacritic sensitive and may perform better.

```
{
  "scalar-type": "string",
  "path-expression": "/pathSyntax",
  "collation": "http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1",
  "range-value-positions": false,
  "invalid-values": "reject"
}
```

Depending upon the default collation of your query, you may also need to specify the collation as an option in your [`cts:path-range-query`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:path-range-query):

```
cts:path-range-query("/pathSyntax", "=", $Type, "collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1")
```